# Angular: ng generate not working

Tags: angular-cli

```
Apples-MacBook-Pro:Basic Atreya$ ng generate component servers

/Users/apple/Projects/NodeProject/Basic/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:89
            throw new InvalidConfigError(common_tags_1.stripIndent `
            ^

InvalidConfigError: Parsing '/Users/apple/Projects/NodeProject/Basic/.angular-cli.json' failed. Ensure the file is valid JSON.
Error: Unexpected string in JSON at position 547
    at Function.fromConfigPath (/Users/apple/Projects/NodeProject/Basic/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:89:19)
    at Function.fromProject (/Users/apple/Projects/NodeProject/Basic/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:67:46)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Projects/NodeProject/Basic/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:10:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Comment: This looks like you are trying to run an ng generate command outside of a Angular CLI application folder. Are you certain you are using this properly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are calling `ng generate` from a project that is not an `angular-cli` created. It is trying to find `angular.cli.json` and fails.

Try to navigate to the folder that has been generated using `ng new` and run the command there.